# React Router + SSR + Hydrate

Tags: react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

I have a route that "internally" to our server configuration points to:

`{
    path: '/product/:sku',
    component: Product,
},`

we have some "magic" happen with nginx proxies that routes an external 'search engine friendly url (SEF)' to point at a particular `sku`.

This redirect works fine internally and our SSR rendered product page loads as expected. However as soon as the React.hydrate happens it seems to look at the client side SEF url and it doesnt match the server side url and so it thinks its incorrect (or at least thats all i can think of) and then re-renders a blank white page. 
Any ideas does react router have some way to match against a url from outside to inside.

Comment: Difficult to diagnose the problem without a better understanding of the "magic" you mention...

Comment: The magic doesn’t seem to be the problem, if the internal url doesn’t match the external url react router seems to think it’s incorrect. Which is confirmed if I disable is and prevent hydrate it will then just have the see rendered react page